# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, dll

Tying to build a freshly cloned project, when i build i get this error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

Things I've tried

Removing the reference and adding back in

changing build properties from debug to release

disabling strong name verification via command line using the command "sn -Vr 
Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure.dll"

i've tried updating the reference to latest / previous versions

Everything I try and nothing seems to work, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In app.config or Web.config, delete the following:

```
, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Comment: Hi Geoffrey! Thanks for the suggestion but that doesnt seem to work either. any other ideas? Could this be a permissions fault? i'm might not have proper access to use the dll? just a thought.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is to check in the .csproj file for the project, and check that the Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure <Reference> has a <HintPath> that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

download [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure/) nuget package and this will work for you.

Comment: For user secrets Microsoft has divided in two different dll in .net fw not core. 
first for config file which stores in appdata
second for Environment variable

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework:

For me the issue was that I had to change the Version=1.0.0.0 in my web.config to match what was loaded and referenced in the web application references.  Right click [Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure] and go to properties and you'll see the version at the bottom.  For me it was Version=2.0.0.0.